# Multiplication of two column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the result of the multiplication between column `fee` and column `duration`, but when I do `Select duration * fee` I get `0`!

Also, every column * fee gives me 0...

This is the create table script.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `simvoip` 
(   
`prefix` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
`destination` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   
`fee` varchar(45) DEFAULT  NULL,   
`calldate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
`dst` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
`dstchannel` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
`duration` varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8$$*
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: you should first change the columns fee and duration to type Double

Comment: Have you tried storing numbers as `INT` or `NUMERIC` or `FLOAT` rather than as `VARCHAR`?  `123` is a number, it can be arithmatecially malipulated. `'123'` is a string and may as well be `'one two three'`, which can not be arithmetically manipulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you need to convert string columns into number.

try this:

```
SELECT CAST(`duration` AS DECIMAL(10,4)) * CAST(`fee` AS DECIMAL(10,4))
FROM   `simvoip`
```

BTW, you are adding extra work for the server to convert the values first before multiplying them. Why not store the as `DECIMAL` or `Double`?

Comment: how is your data formatted in `fee` and `duration`? check this @ sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0348f/2

Comment: Bizarre ..! There is a problem somewhere...Thanks John for your Help

Comment: did it answer your question? if not, let's  find another solution :)

Comment: I still have the same problem with the fee column, it's like a black hole, every value multiplied by the fee column become ZERO...!

Comment: can provide a screenshot of your records? it may help a lot :)

Comment: This is a sceenShot : http://www.4shared.com/photo/NwHqjCVP/test.html
Hope it Helps you..

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply text values. You need to convert them to numbers, using `CAST(fee as integer)` or whatever.. Alternatively, why not **store numbers as numbers**?