# MySQL database queries

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have two columns namely, "item_price", "number_purchased" and "total_sales" in a table named "SALES". I want a query that multiplies the data in "item_price" column with the data in the "number_purchased" column and then displaying the results in the "total_sales" column.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it demonstrates no research effort and no attempts to solve the problem before posting on SO.

Comment: Also, duplicate.  No research effort shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825091/multiplication-of-two-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
   SELECT ITEM_PRICE, NUMBER_PURCHASED, ITEM_PRICE*NUMBER_PURCHASED AS TOTAL_SALES 
    FROM SALES
```

If you want to save the results in an existing column:

```
UPDATE SALES SET TOTAL_SALES=ITEM_PRICE*NUMBER_PURCHASED
```

Comment: Just make sure item_price and number_purchased are numeric.  If not, you will need to cast/convert them.

Comment: A column like TOTAL_SALES in the database would probably be redundant since you can do the calculations later on.